# C++ Library Reference

Tags: c++

I'm looking for some sort of API for the C++ Library Reference.
Does any one know of one that lists all (or most) of the functions' interface in the library.

Is there any UML or similar diagram exist for the standard C++ library?

Comment: What is "API for the C++ Library Reference"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) quite a bit in the past.  It also has some diagrams.

Comment: caveat: it's a good reference, but not an authoritative one. That said, I uses it a lot too.

Answer (score 2):

For a complete reference, you've got a couple of choices. You can either purchase a copy of the current standard (or, you can download a draft of the upcoming standard). The alternative is to use your compilers documentation. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is good, and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/) has doxygen comments.

For simple problems I tend to use [SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html)'s reference.

Answer (score 2):

go to google type `libstdc++ api filetype:pdf` u ll get a pdf wid abt 4000 pages wid the complete reference

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at : http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/